# Where to inject code to print out motion vectors and DC coefficients inside ffmpeg lib

Tags: c, ffmpeg, mpeg-4

For research purposes, I need to extract information about motion vectors and DC coefficients from an MPEG4 video.

I have inserted many `printf` into virtually each function inside `mpeg4videodec.c` and recompiled the `ffmpeg` library then executed `demuxing_decoding.c` which is available at: http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/demuxing_decoding_8c-example.html

Surprisingly none of those `printf` I inserted was shown in the console. Can you give me some hints which file(s) in the `ffmpeg` library should I touch in order to print out `MVectors` and `DC` coefficients of a MPEG4 video file?

Comment: @Lampis I think you have managed to do that before?

Comment: May be you could search for something like `freopen` to assert that file you trying to write in (`stdout` or `stderr`) are not closed. If you do not find, a debugger could be a good starting point

Comment: I need to know where to inject code to print out DC Coefficients, I don't think mpeg4videodec.c is the right place to inject code. Which file in the ffmpeg library then?

Comment: @Karoly Horvath good idea!

Answer (score 0):

The motion vectors can be found inside the 
 `motion_est_template.c`
 file in FFMPEG for MPEG4. Specifically, whichever motion estimator is being called. Diamond being the default. I had inserted my `printf` statements in the function `sab_diamond_search()` where i saved the coded picture number, mbx and mby from the MPEGStruct as well as the `best[0]` and `best[1]` which matched the xy value of the motion vector.

Sorry if two years later is too late.